# strip quotes from variable from .env file included in makefile

Tags: makefile, environment-variables

I have a situation where I have an environment variable with space character inside. Some tools do not like quoting the value of the variable, as they will treat the quote as part of the variable.

This is set in a `.env` file.

```sh
PIP_EXTRA_INDEX_URL="https://token@repo https://token@repo"
```

When I include and export this `.env` file in a `Makefile`, I get this warning.

```sh
WARNING: Location '"https://token@repo' is ignored: 
it is either a non-existing path or lacks a specific scheme.
```

But I have seen this behavior as initially mentioned also with other tools. Is there a way to handle this?

In the Makefile, I include it like below.

```
include .env
export

build:
    docker build --build-arg PIP_EXTRA_INDEX_URL -t myimage .
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works like this.

```
build:
    docker build --build-arg PIP_EXTRA_INDEX_URL=$(PIP_EXTRA_INDEX_URL) -t myimage .
```

Comment: Please edit your question to add this information: don't add an answer with this information.

Comment: But it's the solution to the problem.

Comment: You don't need the `export` here.

Answer (score 1):

Makefiles are not shell scripts and it is not possible to use the same syntax to define variables in both the shell and in make, except in very limited situations.

In the shell, you can have multiple assignments on the same line or even run programs on the same line.  So, if your assignment has whitespace in it you have to quote it as you've done here.

In make, the syntax of an assignment is that all text after the assignment (and leading whitespace) becomes the value of the variable and there is no quoting needed; any quotes that are seen are kept as part of the variable value.

So, in the shell this assignment:

```
PIP_EXTRA_INDEX_URL='https://token@repo https://token@repo'
```

sets the shell variable `PIP_EXTRA_INDEX_URL` to the value `https://token@repo https://token@repo` ... note the quotes are stripped from the value by the shell.

In make this assignment:

```
PIP_EXTRA_INDEX_URL='https://token@repo https://token@repo'
```

sets the shell variable `PIP_EXTRA_INDEX_URL` to the value `'https://token@repo https://token@repo'` ... note the quotes are **not** stripped from the value by make.

So if you use this value in a recipe like this:

```
do something "$(PIP_EXTRA_INDEX_URL)"
```

then make will expand that variable and you'll get:

```
do something "'https://token@repo https://token@repo'"
```

(including quotes) and that's your problem.

Comment: In your original question, that I answered, you didn't show the makefile rule that you were using.  I thought you were using the variable in a recipe as described in my answer.  After you changed your question to show the real use case, it's clear that didn't match my expectations.  Lesson to self: always ask for the question to be clarified rather than assuming what the problem is.

Comment: Oh I see, you started writing before I included more details in my question. My bad sorry.

Comment: There's no difference: `MYVAR` will contain the same identical text as `PIP_EXTRA_INDEX_URL`.  If it works with `$(MYVAR)` then you might as well have just used `$(PIP_EXTRA_INDEX_URL)`.  The reason it "works" is that you've not added quotes around it (see the quotes in my example).  If you know the value has quotes, and you only use it in places where the quotes don't matter (that is, the shell will strip them for you) you win.  If not, you lose.